# Calculate the Mean of last 3 records in a timeseries data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Facing problem in calculating the mean of last 3 records in my timeseries dataframe. Below is the sample of data

```
serial,date,feature1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1,5/19/2017,-5.199338,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
5,6/12/2017,-25.199338,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
5,6/23/2017,5.199338,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
2,7/1/2017,8.199338,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1,7/17/2017,3.199338,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1,7/29/2017,76.199338,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
2,8/19/2017,13.199338,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
6,9/19/2017,785.199338,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
3,10/28/2017,5.199338,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
4,11/2/2017,67.199338,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
2,11/28/2017,49.199338,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
2,12/29/2017,20.199338,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
3,1/29/2018,19.199338,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
4,3/13/2018,-15.199338,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1,3/28/2018,-5.199338,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

The requirement is to add another column say `mean` in dataframe, which will be the Mean value (for column `feature1`) of last 3 rows with similar `serial` numbers. This has to be done for every row.

for example the calculation of mean for below row

```
1,3/28/2018,-5.199338,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

will be done by using below dataset -

```
1,7/17/2017,3.199338,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1,7/29/2017,76.199338,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1,3/28/2018,-5.199338,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

after calculating mean the row whould lo0k like

```
serial,date,feature1,mean_feature1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
...........................
1,3/28/2018,-5.199338,24.7333,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

My problem statement is similar to below article but it is using rolling which requires definite window which is random in my case -
[Pandas: Average value for the past n days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36969174/pandas-average-value-for-the-past-n-days)

Expected Output -

```
serial,date,feature1,mean_feature1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1,5/19/2017,-5.199338,-5.199338,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
5,6/12/2017,-25.199338,-25.199338,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
5,6/23/2017,5.199338,-10.0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
2,7/1/2017,8.199338,8.199338,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1,7/17/2017,3.199338,-1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1,7/29/2017,76.199338,24.xxx,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
2,8/19/2017,13.199338,10.7xx,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
6,9/19/2017,785.199338,785.199338,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
3,10/28/2017,5.199338,5.199338,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
4,11/2/2017,67.199338,67.199338,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
2,11/28/2017,49.199338,23.xxx,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
2,12/29/2017,20.199338,27.xx,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
3,1/29/2018,19.199338,12.xxx,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
4,3/13/2018,-15.199338,26.xxxx,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1,3/28/2018,-5.199338,24.xxxxx,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Please note values are approximately calculated for column 'mean_feature1`

Comment: how do you determine "similar serial numbers"?

Comment: @Cut7er, similar serial numbers means the values in the column (first column in dataset)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`rolling`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) and `mean`:

```
#if necessary remove only NaNs columns
df = df.dropna(how='all', axis=1)
df['mean_feature1'] = (df.groupby('serial',sort=False)['feature1']
                        .rolling(3, min_periods=1).mean()
                        .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df)

    serial        date    feature1  mean_feature1
0        1   5/19/2017   -5.199338      -5.199338
1        5   6/12/2017  -25.199338     -25.199338
2        5   6/23/2017    5.199338     -10.000000
3        2    7/1/2017    8.199338       8.199338
4        1   7/17/2017    3.199338      -1.000000
5        1   7/29/2017   76.199338      24.733113
6        2   8/19/2017   13.199338      10.699338
7        6   9/19/2017  785.199338     785.199338
8        3  10/28/2017    5.199338       5.199338
9        4   11/2/2017   67.199338      67.199338
10       2  11/28/2017   49.199338      23.532671
11       2  12/29/2017   20.199338      27.532671
12       3   1/29/2018   19.199338      12.199338
13       4   3/13/2018  -15.199338      26.000000
14       1   3/28/2018   -5.199338      24.733113
```

If want [`insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) column by position:

```
df.insert(3, 'mean_feature1', (df.groupby('serial',sort=False)['feature1']
                                 .rolling(3, min_periods=1).mean()
                                 .reset_index(drop=True)))
```

Comment: i think you need to sort on date after groupby before apply().

Comment: What I am looking for is adding one column in my original dataframe for all the records..

Comment: @JagrutTrivedi - be need `df['mean_feature1'] = df.groupby('serial',sort=False)['feature1'].transform(lambda x: x.tail(3).mean())` ? What is expected output?

Comment: @JagrutTrivedi - Or need `df['mean_feature1'] = df.groupby('serial',sort=False)['feature1'].rolling(3, min_periods=1).mean().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)` ?